# Function execution delayed (after requesting for access permission) IOS

Tags: ios, swift3, ekeventstore

I need permission for using iOS's reminder and for that i'm doing this :

```
switch EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .reminder) {
case .authorized:                    
    print("Access granted")
    //everything's normal here
    //executing my function here

case .denied:
    print("Access denied")
case .notDetermined:       
    print("not defined yet")

    //No determined so asking for permission
    self.eventStore.requestAccess(to: .reminder) { (granted, error) -> Void in
        if granted == true {
            print("permission granted")

           //executing my function here after getting permissions but this piece of code executes after a long delay 
           //this piece of codes are executing after a while say 5-10 seconds

        }else if error != nil{       
            print("ther's an error : \(error)")
        }            
    }

default:
    print("Case Default")
}
```

As explained above when app prompts user for permission of Reminder and user grants the permission my next Function got executed but after a while (5-10 seconds)

anyone can explain why is it happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completion of requestAccess doesn't get called on main thread. Put `permissions granted` code inside Dispatch Async:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  print("permission granted")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Requesting permissions is purely an Asynchornous process and you can't just execute the function immediately as that can't be controlled from our code. App code can request for permission and we get the delegates callback handler when the permissions are granted by OS based on which there is a lag in actually receiving the requested permissions.

It's also possible that you are requesting the permissions from the thread/block which is not running on the main UI thread and there would be invisible delay in execution of that code. You must check the code which initiates the permission request.